# Process gets Killed by Linux OS - No OOM Log in /var/log files

Tags: linux, process, virtual-machine, redhat, kill-process

We deployed multiple JVMs in a Linux System along with a Node.js and a mongod server instance. It is https enabled micro services architecture.

Some of the above listed processes are getting down randomly. There is no clue why they are down.

No OOM related log trace in /var/log  syslog files, Is it possible for linux to kill the process other than OOM.

What are the possible syslog errors ? ( I have the complete /var/log files )

Where to look to identify the actual issue ? We have no clue on this... Sombody can help please to trace the process end to end

Comment: How are you deploying the JVMs? Is it a web app deployed on a server?

Comment: Do you know for sure they're getting killed by sigkill? (Because they're simply dying due to software errors, you should be getting core dumps (if you've enabled them) with all the information that should be necessary to diagnose the error.)

Comment: @yogur, no they are rest exposed jetty containers

Comment: Is this in a virtualized or container environment? If yes, what kind?

Comment: @Florian Weimer, It is a virtualized environment

Comment: @M.Gopal, which kind?

Comment: @Florian Weimer, Sorry,  Can you pl elaborate your question. Newbie

Comment: @M.Gopal, what is the hypervisor?

Comment: @Florian Weimer, Hypervisor detected: VMware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are starting these JVM processes in the background, did you use nohup to make sure they ignore SIGHUP? Also it would be wise to redirect the output of these processes to the output files. 
E.g.

```
nohup node server1.js >& server1.out &
```

And then you can investigate in those files for any possible messages if there are any.

Comment: We have this kind of setup only. will it give the message reg. the os kill of that particular process ?

Comment: If it gets killed by SIGKILL for whatever reasons then the process won't get any chance to do anything about it and will die immediately. Didn't you see anything in the logs?